# MiKTeX 2.9 Does NOT Support `hypernat`

Tags: packages, installing, miktex

Today I migrated from MiKTeX 2.8 to MiKTeX 2.9 (on Windows XP). Starting to compile old LaTeX files, I noticed the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `hypernat.sty' not found.
```

A little search revealed the following page: http://az.ctan.org/pkg/hypernat.
It says that `hypernat` package is not available in MiKTeX.

I further read [MiKTeX FAQ](http://docs.miktex.org/faq/faq.html#missingpkg). Among other things, it says:

> [A package might be missing from MiKTeX] if the package's license doesn't meet the requirements of the [Debian Free Software Guidelines](http://www.debian.org/social_contract#guidelines).

To me, it seems that `hypernat` license was once compatible with Debian Free Software Guidelines, but it then became incompatible, and the MiKTeX team decided to remove it from their latest distribution (2.9). Am I right?

Next, I want a solution for this. I just want to somehow install `hypernat` on the MiKTeX. I downloaded [`hypernat.zip`](http://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/hypernat.zip) and tried:

`mpm --verbose --install hypernat.zip`

but apparently MiKTeX does not recognize this package.

Before posting any solutions, please kindly note that my environment is such that:

1. I don't want to use distributions other than MiKTeX (say TeX Live).
2. I don't want to use alternatives to `hypernat`.

Comment: You could have a look at [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

New versions of `hyperref` and `natbib` don't need `hypernat` at all. So the omission should not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The section »[Integrating Local Additions](http://docs.miktex.org/2.8/manual/localadditions.html)« of the MiKTeX manual should help you in adding this package to your system. Note that the package won't show up in the package list of the MPM thus you will have to update the package manually.