# hyperref problem

Tags: hyperref

I am using a LaTeX template from  http://aesm.asso.univ-poitiers.fr/files/Modele_Latex.zip.

My question is when I compile the `these.tex` I have a small problem with hyperlinks. They aren't exact especially the first page and some other pages.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).  It really helps **you** get the help you require more quickly.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

Comment or exclude the line 22 in `.\Classes\aesm_edspia.cls` file:

```
\usepackage{hypernat}
```

New versions of `hyperref` and `natbib` don't need `hypernat` at all.

See question [MiKTeX 2.9 Does NOT Support hypernat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7340/miktex-2-9-does-not-support-hypernat).